# Recreate git repository from .git folder from stash

Tags: git, bitbucket-server

Thanks in advance for any help. I had an instance of Atlassian Stash, with a repository on it. The instance died, and the only thing I have left, is a couple of numbered folders that seem to be the ".git" folders of a repo (i.e. with the hooks, logs, refs, objects, subfolders inside). Is there any way to recreate the repositories from these folders? If so, how?
Just to clarify, I don't have the files themselves, I only have the content inside these folders. I need to recreate the versioned files from this somehow.

Comment: Is it a complete `.git` folder? I.e. with `HEAD` and `config` files too, as well as the `objects` directory? If so, try a normal `git clone` and see if it works.

Comment: does `git reset --hard` work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to do a `git clone` of the .git folder

```
git clone file:///opt/git/project.git
```

If that works it will copy the Git repository.

Alternative: have you got any clients that have `git pull`ed from the Atlassian Stash server lately? You can simply use the `.git` repository of the freshest client as a new server repository.